# AutoCompleteTextView margin for the dropdown items

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, listitem

I have AutoCompleteTextView and I want the textview component to have value fill_parent for the width but I want the dropdown items to have margins from the right(10dip) and from the left side (10dip).

How can I set margin just on the dropdown items ?

Answer (score 0):

Make the layout.xml for your row entries and then set your own adapter to the autoCompleteTextView.
This is same as customizing the view of any list by your own layouts.

Comment: This works in theory :(, I have tried but doesn't help, the list item is still presented as fill parent with no margin, even the margins are set

Comment: I do not need padding I need margin

Comment: if you give the padding to the main layout of row it will serve the same purpose

Comment: not in my case, I need to see the background on the left and on the right side, if I was able to do this with padding I wouldn't start this thread at all :-), but the problem is that I want to set the margin...